Would a voltage appear across the switch?

This is a situation of a de-energizing transient. My question is, would a voltage appear across the switch even in the presence of the discharge resistor \$R_{2}\$?
I am asking this because, I wanna know how adding the resistor \$R_{2}\$ would help in controlling the arc across the switch that would have formed without it.
Source of the figure:
-Circuit analysis (theory and practice)-2nd edition.

What is on the other side of the switch?

@vir There's nothing but a battery

There will always be voltage over the opened switch, unless the circuit voltage happens to always match the battery voltage. I am sure your intention is to ask something else than this. Can you explain better what you are after?

@Justme can I calculate that voltage? Because the reason we put the resistor $R_{2}$ is avoiding the arc that would form without adding it. So, You're saying that there is a voltage over the switch. However, it is small enough to avoid the formation of that unwanted arc, right?

Do the KVL to find Vsw voltage. We have 120V - Vsw + 2400V = 0 Thus, Vsw = 2520V

@G36, I don't think we can apply KVL to an open loop as such

Yes, we can apply it. Or we can use "common sense", the voltage on the right side of a switch is 120V and on the left side is -2400V therefore the voltage drop across Vsw is 120V - (-2400V) = 2520V

@Jack You can calculate it, but the book already calculates the whole circuit for you in the text so there is nothing left to calculate. If there is -2400V on one switch terminal, and 120V on another switch terminal, you know how much is across the switch.

That part of the book deals with inductive transients.
In that circuit the inductor current is charged to 4A, from 120V supply and 30 ohm resistor R1.
So in short, the answer is, yes, there will be a 2400 volt transient when 4A must flow in 600 ohm resistor, after switch is opened.

My question is about the switch. @Justme commented that there always gonna be a voltage drop across the switch. So, there gonna be a voltage across the switch, but not big enough to cause any arc, right?

2400V is enough to cause an arc. 24V is enough to cause an arc. The question is whether your switch is designed to break the circuit despite the arc and how quickly will the contacts erode.

@vir Let's say the $R_{2}$ represent a Neon lamp. So, upon opening the switch, I would observe 1-the Neon lamp lights 2- an acrc across the switch?

Yes but I would try with a 9V battery instead of a 120V supply.

@Jack The whole circuit is explained in the text right next to the circuit. What exactly is unclear? And if there is an arc across the switch, it depends on (a) at what voltage the switch will arc (we don't know) and (b) if the voltage exceeds that arcing threshold voltage or not.
